# PHP заполнение массива циклом For

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите начинающему.

Задача:

1.1. Абстрактный класс TriangleAbstract.php реализует конструктор в котором автоматически задаются стороны треугольника. У класса есть несколько абстрактных методов, которые должны быть реализованы в классе Triangle. Следовательно, необходимо создать класс Triangle, унаследоваться от класса TriangleAbstract. Для абстрактных методов создать реализацию необходимых функций описанных в комментариях к ним в родительском методе.

1.2. Созданный класс Triangle необходимо подключить к файлу triangleTest. В массив triangleArray добавить 10 объектов типа Triangle (Условно, поместить в массив 10 треугольников).

1.3. Пройтись циклом фор-ич по triangleArray и выполнить реализованные методы. Вывести результат для каждого треугольника, каждый вывод подписывается с пояснением, что означает данный параметр (или к какому методу относится).

Пункт 1.1 сделан. Вопрос по пункту 1.2

Как заполнить массив, если его надо заполнить циклом for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то такое

```
$aTr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $oTr = new Triangle(параметры конструктора);
    // делаем что нужно с $oTr
    $aTr[] = $oTr;
}
```

Comment: Все хорошо, спасибо.
Но при принте массива, выдает просто "Array"
Как можно посмотреть все значения каждого треугольника?

Comment: Есть функции var_dump(массив) и print_r(массив), попробуйте их.

Comment: Действительно, благодарю!